# How to combine rows with the same id from a csv with php

Tags: php, excel, sorting, csv, merge

I have a csv with two columns "id" and "name" and I want to merge the rows that share the same id and to have them be separated by a comma.

```
id      name
39695   NFL: Cowboys @ Giants
39699   NFL: Colts @ Bears
39699   NFL: Steelers @ Broncos
39699   NFL: Eagles @ Browns
39699   NFL: Panthers @ Buccaneers
```

into

```
id      name
39695   NFL: Cowboys @ Giants
39699   NFL: Colts @ Bears, NFL: Steelers @ Broncos, NFL: Eagles @ Browns, NFL: Panthers @ Buccaneers
```

All I need is just an echo back out or a new .csv file.

Thank you for the help.

**edit

```
<"?php

$lines = file('sport3.csv');

foreach($lines as $line)
{
list($id, $name) = explode(',', $line);
$merged[$id][] = $name;
}

foreach($merged as $id => $vals)
{
echo '"' . $id . '", "' . implode(',', $vals) . '\"\n';
}
?>
```

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Comment: $lines = file('sport3.csv');

foreach($lines as $line)
{
`code`    list($id, $name) = explode(',', $line);
    $merged[$id][] = $name;
}

foreach($merged as $id => $vals)
{
    echo '"' . $id . '", "' . implode(',', $vals) . '\"\n';
}

Comment: Please go back and edit the question and put your code in the question

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to use specifically designed for CSV functions in PHP:

```
// parse thru data
$mergedData = array();
$handle = fopen('sport3.csv', 'r');
if (!$handle) throw new Exception("Can't open original CSV file");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    list($id, $name) = $data;
    if (empty($mergedData[$id])) $mergedData[$id] = array();
    $mergedData[$id][] = $name;
}
fclose($handle);

// save merged data
if (count($mergedData) > 0) {
    $handle = fopen('sport3-merged.csv', 'w');
    if (!$handle) throw new Exception("Can't open CSV file for merged data");
    foreach($mergedData as $id => $vals) {
        array_unshift($vals, $id);
        if (!fputcsv($handle, $vals)) throw new Exception("Can't write data to merged CSV file");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble implementing this, would you mind taking a look at the page? https://people.rit.edu/cak5074/536/class/typecal.html

Comment: Your php code does not get executed. Try using .php extension instead of .html. And if that does not work, you have to talk to the site sys admin to tell you what extension to use for php code or to allow it to be executed in first place.